# Effect size and statistical significance correspondence

Tags: statistical-significance, effect-size, cohens-d, research-design

While I understand that it is possible to have a small effect size with statistical significance and a large effect size without statistical significance, is it ever possible to find this across two participants within the same study (on the same outcome measure)?  I am looking at a single-subject design study where this appears to be reported, but it seems counterintuitive to me. Surely if a large effect size is not significant for one participant, a smaller effect size couldn't be significant for another?

I'd really appreciate any insight on this.